# Tensorflow: save and restore variable issue

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to save and restore variable in tensorflow?

I got a problem. My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 2], dtype=tf.float32, name='v1'))
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(v1)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, 'model.ckpt')
    print "model saved in file:", save_path
    v1 = v1 + 1
    print sess.run(v1)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    print sess.run(v1)
```

Result:

```
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]

[[ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]

[[ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]
```

I expect to get:

```
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]

[[ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]

[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

What mistake did I make?

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main issues in your code:

1. The line `v1 = v1 + 1` creates a new TensorFlow `Tensor` and binds it to the Python variable `v1`, but does not change the value that is in the TensorFlow `Variable` you created with the name `"v1"`. As a result, when you later call `sess.run(v1)`, you are evaluating the new tensor that adds 1 to the original variable, rather than reading the value from the tensor.

   Instead, to add ones to a variable, you should use the following:

   ```
   increment_op = v1.assign_add(tf.ones([2, 2]))
   sess.run(increment_op)
   ```
2. The [`tf.train.import_meta_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#import_meta_graph) call *recreates* the original graph, and in doing so adds new nodes to your graph, including a new [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver). It is useful when you haven't already constructed the graph (or don't have the program to do that available). Since you have already constructed your graph, you only need to use `saver.restore(sess, 'model.ckpt')`.

The following program should produce your expected behavior:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 2], dtype=tf.float32, name='v1'))
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(v1)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, './model.ckpt')
    print "model saved in file:", save_path

    # Create an op to increment v1, run it, and print the result.   
    increment_op = v1.assign_add(tf.ones([2, 2]))
    sess.run(increment_op)
    print sess.run(v1)

    # Restore from the checkpoint saved above.
    saver.restore(sess, './model.ckpt')
    print sess.run(v1)
```

Comment: It's really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Although, the selected answer tells us what should be done but doesn't explain why exactly you are getting the unexpected answer. I am explaining for anyone who comes here later.

In Tensorflow, if you already have a graph and you again import the same graph after saving it, your graph operations will not be replaced, rather they Tensorflow is designed to create new variables by adding suffix like _1, _2 etc. For example, in your case, before you did:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
Your graph had a variable called v1. After you import the same graph, your variable v1 is not going to be replaced, rather, a new variable v1_1 will be added to the graph. So, the size of the graph will be doubled. Since v1 has not changed by loading the graph you still get v1's old value(all 1).

If you want to reset the graph, you have to use tf.reset_default_graph()
 before importing the graph again as explained in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph). If you do import after this and print v1, you will get an all 0 v1.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#import_meta_graph) may shed some light on this. I ran your file with a modification or two:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 2], dtype=tf.float32, name='v1'))
saver = tf.train.Saver()

tf.add_to_collection('v1', v1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print sess.run(v1)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, 'model.ckpt')
    print "model saved in file:", save_path
    v1 = v1 + 1
    print sess.run(v1)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    print sess.run(v1)
```

Notice the `tf.add_to_collection` call. After that, I ran this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
print sess.run(tf.get_collection('v1')[0])
```

With output:

```
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

Looks like restoring things won't actually modify your current computation graph, and you need to use collections to get what you want.